# unscrambling game in discord.js problems with selecting random line in text files

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to make an unscrambling game in discord.js! (you can get the idea of the game through the message that's supposed to be sent through the channel) The scrambling thing is working fine, but I seem to be having problems selecting a random line in the file. I use I have this code:

```
const rl = require('readline-specific')
var started = 'true'


let randomline = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1525) + 1;
rl.oneline('./words.txt', randomline, function(err, res) {
    if (err) console.error(err)
    console.log(res)
    let correctword = res
    message.channel.send('The word to guess is: "' + res.shuffle() + '". use "+guess <yourguess>" if you think you know what it is!');
})
```

but this does not seem to work.  It doesn't give any error log or have any action in chat, or log res. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: it seems my other line `if(started === 'false')` { which is s variable false if the game isnt started and true when it is. I dont understand because i have it set to false with my command +reset . What is going on?

Comment: My only guess is that `rl.oneline` isn't being ran. Place a `console.log()` before you call it just to double check.

Comment: my line before this `if(started === 'false') {` isnt triggering even though i have a command that sets it to that? why is this happening?

Comment: use a `console.log(started)` after its set to false, any where it's being set to true ~~even if that line shouldn't run~~ and before the if statement.

Comment: hey... just to double check... is started a true or false variable or a string... you're checking for a string `started === 'false'` you should check for a boolean `started === false`

Answer (score 0):

After testing your provided code, my guess is that you assign `started` to `"false"` in a scope not visible to the provided code + `if(started === 'false')`. My solution is to declare `started` at the start of your script and then assign values to it, like:

```
//Start of the script
var started = 'false';
...
//+reset
started = 'false'
...
if(started === 'false'){
const rl = require('readline-specific')
var started = 'true'


let randomline = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1525) + 1;
rl.oneline('./words.txt', randomline, function(err, res) {
    if (err) console.error(err)
    console.log(res)
    let correctword = res
    message.channel.send('The word to guess is: "' + res.shuffle() + '". use "+guess <yourguess>" if you think you know what it is!');
})
}
```

Also, what is `res.shuffle()`? Is it `String` constructor modification?
If not, please check that you didn't mistake `String.shuffle()` for `shuffle()`.